# ReportEvent limits

Tags: winapi, events, logging

I am trying to write a detailed error message to the system log using the `ReportEventW` function. Unfortunately, I am encountering problems which are apparently related to the limits within the function but I can't find any real documentation of them: there is a documented limit on `dwDataSize` and another limit on the maximum length of each string. I am not violating any of these limits, but I am still receiving a FALSE and GetLastError reports RPC_S_INVALID_BOUND.

Through testing, I found that for my test case the limit is caused by the number of strings (`wNumStrings`), with 203 being the most I can put through correctly (additionally, for 204-206 strings the `ReportEventW` will return a TRUE but **will not write to the log!**). If I add 1024 dummy characters to the first line, I once again get an error and have to decrease the number of lines, as far as I can tell, by the same number of characters I added earlier, which would indicate that some total character limit on the whole message is coming to play. Unfortunately, I can't match it against any documented limit even if I ignore what the limits should apply to - my value of about 33300 characters is close to the value 31839 characters (max. length of each string), but sufficiently higher than that to make me discard the theory that the limit on a length of individual string also applies to the total length of the whole message. Apparently, if I add extra raw data, the limit goes down again, which suggests a limitation on the size of the whole event log record.

My questions are:

1) Does anyone know the actual limits for writing to the event log?

2) Do these limits change with the different operating systems? All my tests were performed on Win10 x64, but I have a nasty suspicion that with different OSes, I will encounter a different limitation.

3) Is this documented somewhere?

Thanks.

**Actual code (added on request)**

```
procedure WriteToEventLog(const Messages: array of string; const RawData: AnsiString);
const
  MaxStringCount = High(Word); // je to WORD! Realne se limit zda byt mnohem mensi
  MaxRawDataLen = 61440;
  EmptyMessage = #0#0#0#0;
type
  TPCharArray = array[0..65535] of PChar;
var
  Handle: THandle;
  Msgs: ^TPCharArray;
  MsgCount: integer;
  DataPtr: PAnsiChar;
  DataLen: integer;
  i: Integer;
begin
  MsgCount := Length(Messages);
  if MsgCount > MaxStringCount then
    MsgCount := MaxStringCount;
  Msgs := AllocMem(MsgCount * Sizeof(PChar));
  try
    for i := 0 to Pred(MsgCount) do
    begin
      if Messages[i] = ''
        then Msgs[i] := EmptyMessage
        else Msgs[i] := PChar(Messages[i]);
    end;
    if RawData = '' then
    begin
      DataPtr := nil;
      DataLen := 0;
    end
    else
    begin
      DataPtr := @RawData[1];
      DataLen := Length(RawData);
      if DataLen > MaxRawDataLen then
        DataLen := MaxRawDataLen;
    end;
    Handle := RegisterEventSource(nil, PChar(ParamStr(0)));
    if Handle <> 0 then
    begin
      try
        ReportEvent(Handle, EVENTLOG_ERROR_TYPE, 0, 0, nil, MsgCount, DataLen, Msgs, DataPtr);
      finally
        DeregisterEventSource(Handle);
      end;
    end;
  finally
    FreeMem(Msgs);
  end;
end;
```

It is called with `Messages` array containing rows from an EurekaLog report (one row per message, about 300 rows).

Comment: Can you show the code you are using? Your test code is probably best suited to illustrate the issue.

Comment: @IInspectable: sure, no problem.

Comment: Sorry, I have no proper answer. But regarding (2) of your questions (from [learn.microsoft.com](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winbase/nf-winbase-reporteventa), emphasis added): "There are different size limits on the size of the message data that can be logged _depending on the version of Windows_ used by both the client where the application is run and the server where the message is logged."  - you may have already seen/read this, but anyway ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I can't answer your questions comprehensively, but I just ran into a similar issue. I only used the `wNumStrings` and `lpStrings` parameters and, contrary to documentation, still received the `RPC_S_INVALID_BOUND` error code (1734). On a nagging suspicion, I reduced the number of strings to 256 and it worked. Sure enough, it failed with 257. This was true regardless of the size of the individual strings. There are probably upper limits for individual strings and total message size too, but I didn't bother figuring those out.

TL/DR: `wNumStrings <= 256`